# How to run both Plotly and Cufflinks in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, cufflinks

I'm getting this error.

```
ERROR: cufflinks 0.17.3 has requirement plotly>=4.1.1, but you'll have plotly 3.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

Before I got this error, I got this error.

```
ImportError: 
The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead.
```

Earlier today, I downgraded plotly from 4.1.1 to 3.10, to eliminate the second error, and that action is now causing the first error, mentioned above.

I am testing the code from the link below, just to get some insight into how to create interactive charts.

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/blob/master/plotly/Plotly%20Whirlwind%20Introduction.ipynb

I'd appreciate any guidance anyone can offer.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you'd like to use `cufflinks`?

Comment: It's supposed to make it easier to work with Plotly.  I guess you just throw a Pandas DF into Cufflinks, and it does most of the lift, with minimal code writing.  Anyway, after I updated a couple of libraries, including 'pyarrow', and restated my machine, everything is working now.  Sorry for the false alarm here.

Comment: No worries. But you should really consider looking into the newest version of plotly. Now you can define plotly as a plotting backend for pandas using `pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"` and just run `fig = df.plot()`

Comment: Thanks!  So, so, so many things to learn!!